# C# ConfigurationManager in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have a shared .NET Standard library that was originally being referenced by a .NET 4.8 MVC 4 project. There is a lot of code in this shared library that uses the `ConfigurationManager`, like:

```
var sze = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxAttachmentSize"];
```

This value for `MaxAttachmentSize` (and others) was being stored in the `web.config`.

Now I have a .NET 6 project that I'm building, which will use this same shared project, and I need to find a way to make these configuration app settings work in the new .NET Core application.  What's the best way to do this?

My questions I guess are:

- Is there a way to get `ConfigurationManager` to read from the .NET Core's `appsettings.json` file like it reads from `web.config` in the ASP.NET MVC 4 project?
- If not, is there another configuration reader that I can use instead that will do double duty being able to work for both projects like I need?

The big spanner in the works though is the fact that all calls to `ConfigurationManger` right now are static, so if the .NET Core option could be static as well that would be incredibly helpful. If not, it'll just be more work moving the ASP.NET MVC 4 project to make those settings dependency injection available.

Answer (score 9):

now you can get it even more easy

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

string sze = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:MaxAttachmentSize").Value;
```

after adding to appsettings.json

```
  "AppSettings": {
    "MaxAttachmentSize": "size1",
    "MinAttachmentSize": "size2"
  }
```

Comment: Which package are you using for your code above?  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager?  if so then I get an error that Configuration.GetSection need an object reference to work.
if you're talking about Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, then that doesn't work either because it also needs an instantiation of IConfiguration

Comment: It depends where in your code you are trying to get appsettings.json data. This code will be working in startup or (program for net6). If you trying to get data in another place you will have to inject IConfiguration.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue.  ConfigurationManager from net framework is a static method, which is what my shared project is using.  Ideally i would find another static way of getting the appsettings.json variables

Comment: @Phil The only static way I know is to create a global static variable. From inside of startup you can assign value  or even the whole config content. the most common way is using dependency injection of config , or injecting of special service

Answer (score 3):

**Using ASP .NET6**

Install NuGet package **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager**

The name of my configuration file is **App.Config**

Content of App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DBConnectionString" value="aa" />
        <add key="DBName" value="bb" />
        <add key="AuthKey" value="cc" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

File reading values, i.e. SettingsService.cs:

```
using namespc = System.Configuration;

namespace Ecommerce_server.Services.SetupOperation
{
    public interface ISettingsService
    {
        string MongoDBConnectionString { get => namespc.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"]!; }

        string DataBaseName { get => namespc.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBName"]!; }

        public string AuthKey { get => namespc.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthKey"]!; }

    }

    public class SettingsService : ISettingsService
    {
        public string MongoDBConnectionString { get => namespc.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConnectionString"]!; }

        public string DataBaseName { get => namespc.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBName"]!; }

        public string AuthKey { get => namespc.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthKey"]!; }

    }
}
```

Note: We had to create a specialized namespace for ConfigurationManger to solve ambiguity.

Comment: How does this interact with the settings hierarchy in .NET 6, where values are overridden based on where they are defined in. For example, Environment variables would override values in appsettings.json. Would that also work here with App.config?

Comment: The configuration system prioritizes the appsettings.json file over the App.config file. The values in the appsettings.json file will take precedence, and any values defined in the App.config file will be ignored. Although you can use both you would not use the same setting in both, otherwise it will not work and it's code duplication. So you should not worry which overriedes which if you do not use the same setting in both.

Answer (score 3):

Reply from Serge is the correct one. .Net 6 and above is suggested to use appsettings.json instead of App.Config and using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configurations namespace`, instead of `System.Configuraiton.ConfigurationManager`
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework#modernize-appsettingsjson) Microsoft describes how to use it.

create a appsettings.json file on the root like below

```
 "AppSettings": {
    "MaxAttachmentSize": "size1",
    "MinAttachmentSize": "size2"
  }
```

Inside the App.xaml.cs get an instance of IConfiguration

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace WebSiteRatings
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static IConfiguration Config { get; private set; }

        public App()
        {
            Config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

And you can access within the app as below

```
string size = App.Config.GetSection("AppSettings:MaxAttachmentSize").Value;
```